# Extract inner array matching values using jq

Tags: json, jq

My json is as shown below:

```
[
[
    {
        "id": "abcd"
    },
    {
        "address": [
            "140 Deco st"
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "id": "xyz"
    },
    {
        "dummy": "This is dummy"
    }
],
[
    {
        "id": "12356"
    },
    {
        "address": [
            "140 Deco st"
        ]
    }
]]
```

Now, I want to capture only those ids who have dummy value of "This is dummy". Some of the data may or may not have dummy and address fields.

I tried below but it gave me error "... cannot have their containment checked"

```
jq -c '.[] | .[] | select(.dummy | contains("This is dummy")) | .[] | .id'
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contains` is quite tricky to use correctly. Since the requirement is:

> to capture only those ids who have dummy value of "This is dummy"

I would suggest:

```
.[]
| select( any(.[]; .dummy == "This is dummy") )
| add
| .id
```

or perhaps (depending on your detailed requirements):

```
.[]
| select( any(.[]; .dummy == "This is dummy") )
| .[]
| .id? // empty
```

Comment: Nice...I tried first one and exactly works as expected but whats the difference between 1st and 2nd soln. Also can you explain a little bit on any()..just tried 2nd one and it doesn't work...gives "Cannot index string with string" error.. but I'm ok with 1st one.

Comment: `any(stream; condition)` asks whether the condition holds for any item in the stream.  I've corrected the second solution and added a "?" for robustness.  For details, see the [tag:jq] manual

Comment: Now 2nd one works but does not give the output and returns empty. I'm not sure whats the difference between the two but I'm totally satisfied with 1st one.

Comment: Check your copy of the second solution has the four lines shown.  The main difference is the handling of: missing "id", {id: null]}, and {id:false}.

Comment: ah ok...Thats fine because id will always be present for me but good to know!!